# Получить коллекцию из класса по типу

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Есть класс с коллекциями:

```
public class CollectionsStorage
{
   public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new();

   public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new();

   // Тип "T" это Animal или Car.
   public IEnumerable<T>? GetObjects<T>()
   {
     // Здесь надо вернуть коллекцию определённого типа.
   }
}
```

Comment: это вы реализовываете свой  "`DbContext`"? Ну есть в целом 2 способа. Если у вас стабильно есть и будет только `Cars` и `Animals`, то хватит и `if (typeof(T) == ...)`. Если вы хотите добавлять новые коллекции-свойства, то вы можете создать приватный статический словарь через рефлексию, в котором будет ключом выступать тип, а значением - коллекция. и потом этот словарь использовать в методе `GetObjects<T>`

Comment: чтоб создать подобный словарь, достаточно в конструкторе `... = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property .PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == ObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<>)).ToDictionary(property => property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0], property.GetValue(this))`

Comment: Мне кажется тут изначально неверный подход, ибо зачем тогда две одинаковые коллекции, но с разными типами в классе, который изначально подразумевает получение разных типов? Это мне кажется даже нарушение SRP, ибо класс выполняет тогда не свою ответственность, распыляясь на разные типы. Что вот мешает сделать генерик класс, а потом делать `var objects = new MyClass<Car>().GetObjects();`? Ну или вон как вы сделали чисто метод, уберите эти локальные коллекции и получайте их внутри метода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Видимо, я поторопился с упрощением реальной ситуации и ввёл Вас в заблуждение, прошу прощения. Реальный класс используется в роли "DbContext" и в нём около 10 различных коллекций сущностей.
При разработке валидатора этих сущностей мне понадобился данный метод. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если реальный объект это экземпляр класса `DbContext`, а объект который вы хотите получить это `DbSet<T>` то всё уже сделано до нас, вот вам метод `Set<T>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-7.0

Comment: Покажите реальную задачу, сейчас вы явно делаете что-то не то...

Comment: @User, @EvgeniyZ. Как раз `Set<T>` я и искал замену, так как класс перестал быть наследником `DbContext`.

Comment: @DiMaAgalakov ну теперь совсем ничего не понятно, приведите реальную задачу, а там посмотрим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости от того как часто будет вызываться этот метод, результаты его работы можно кешировать

```
public class CollectionsStorage
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type , Object> _objects = new Dictionary<Type , Object>();
    
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new();

    // Тип "T" это Animal или Car.
    public IEnumerable<T>? GetObjects<T>()
    {
        if (_objects.TryGetValue(typeof(T) , out Object obj))
        {
            return (IEnumerable<T>)obj;
        }

        PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty)
            .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable<T>)))
            .ToArray();
            
        if (properties.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type T not found");
        }

        if (properties.Length > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type T more than one");
        }

        object result = properties.First().GetValue(this)!;
        _objects[typeof(T)] = result;
        return (IEnumerable<T>)result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это мне и было нужно!